# ASP.NET update panel updating automatically even when conditional

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, conditional-statements

I am working on AJAX update panels for the first time with some success. I have a `<div>` that I want to update when a button (that has postback disabled on it) is clicked.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div style="float: left; height: auto; width: 23%;">
                    <div style="font-size: 20px; padding-top: 11px; border-bottom: solid 1px #dddddd;">
                        Your Logo
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="resultsinnerbox" style="padding-top: 15px; width: 85%; font-size: 12px;">
                        <asp:Literal ID="litLogo" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                        <div style="margin-left: 4.5%; margin-right: 4.5%;">
                            <asp:Literal ID="litLogoDetails" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                            <span class="fileupload">Upload</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Upon the click of the button will do the following

```
litLogoDetails.Text = "Hello"
'UpdatePanel1.Update()
```

However even with the **UpdatePanel** commented out or not the button always updates the panel.

How is that so? when **UpdatePanel1** is Conditional. Also, how is it knowing to update 'UpdatePanel1' when the button is pressed and the `UpdatePanel1.Update()` is commented out.

I need to understand how this is working before I can continue.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: It looks like the button is outside the update panel. If so, then your button click event triggers the complete postback, which makes the update always. So the UpdatePanel has not effect here. To make it effect you need to move the button inside the update panel.

Comment: I found that you can use a <Trigger> but that breaks things as the button is in a model box. :(